# Setting bounds and constraints for scipy dual_annealing

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize, simulated-annealing

I am trying to run simulated annealing to solve the following problem:

*Minimize: Z = 5x + 4y*

*4x + y ≥ 40,*

*2x + 3y ≥ 90,*

*x, y ≥ 0*

However I faced two problems:

1. adding constriants
2. setting the bounds

Scipy's dual_annealing() doesn't support any constraints as parameters (unlike functions such as minimize()). While setting the bounds to [0, inf). I get some errors. My code and the errors are shown below.

```
def obj(v):
    x, y = v
    return 5*x + 4*y

# define range for input
r_min, r_max = 0, np.inf

result = dual_annealing(objective, bounds)
```

If I use bounds as `bounds = [[r_min, r_max], [r_min, r_max]]` I get this error:

```
   640         np.isnan(lower)) or np.any(np.isnan(upper))):
--> 641     raise ValueError('Some bounds values are inf values or nan values')
    642 # Checking that bounds are consistent
    643 if not np.all(lower < upper):

ValueError: Some bounds values are inf values or nan values
```

And if I use `bounds = Bounds(lb=r_min)`, I get this error:

```
--> 639 if (np.any(np.isinf(lower)) or np.any(np.isinf(upper)) or np.any(
    640         np.isnan(lower)) or np.any(np.isnan(upper))):
    641     raise ValueError('Some bounds values are inf values or nan values')
    642 # Checking that bounds are consistent

TypeError: ufunc 'isinf' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
2
```

Most of the examples online use fixed bounds and unconstrained problems. How can I add infinity bounds and constraints?

Comment: You can't. Scipy's dual_annealing doesn't support constraints. That said, what's wrong with solving your linear problem (LP) with [scipy.optimize.linprog](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linprog.html) instead? If you really stuck to dual_annealing, you need to reformulate your constrained optimization problem as an unconstrained problem by using penalty functions. However, I don't see why anyone should prefer this approach to linprog.

Comment: I am trying to solve an optimization problem of a similar form but it has way more variables. So I thought it would be faster to solve if I used a (meta)heuristic algorithm instead of scipy.optimize.linprog. Can you suggest any fast alternative algorithm/method?

Comment: The simplex algorithm and its variants are solely designed to solve LPs by exploiting the mathematical structure of LPs and are exact algorithms, while dual_annealing is just a general meta-heuristic. Thus, the former algorithms will perform **much better** than dual_annealing. ln addition, linprog already interfaces [HiGHS](https://highs.dev/), a state-of-the-art LP solver. TLDR: Use linprog. If it's not fast enough, come back again.

Comment: I tried lingprog it was much faster than I expected it to be, thanks! However, it still took about a minute or so to complete. Speed is more important to me and I don't need to have high accuracy and the approximate result is also suitable for my purpose. I thought to use the Genetic Algorithm but depending on the number of iterations it can be slow. I would appreciate any feedback on possible (meta) heuristic methods.

Comment: Please provide your full optimization problem and show what you've done so far with linprog. Otherwise, it's nearly impossible to help properly.

Comment: I added the mathematical formulation of my problem and the CPLEX code. Unfortunately, I don't have access to my Scipy's code but I followed the documentation to implement it

Comment: We need a [minimal **reproducible** example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) containing all required data so that we can copy-paste the code since our mind-reading skills are limited. That said, you are putting multiple different solvers (dual_annealing, linprog, cplex) into play while your question is tagged with scipy. In addition, your initial question (how to solve the problem with dual_annealing) is already answered, so I'd recommend posting a separate question if you need help with your Cplex implementation.